Configure HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler not working
I want to implement HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler in my spring-boot project. However I cannot get my configuration to work.
This is my implementation
import org.springframework.core.MethodParameter
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component
import org.springframework.web.context.request.NativeWebRequest
import org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler
import org.springframework.web.method.support.ModelAndViewContainer


@Component
class HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerImpl(val delegate: HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler): HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler {


    override fun supportsReturnType(returnType: MethodParameter): Boolean {
        return delegate.supportsReturnType(returnType)
    }

    override fun handleReturnValue(
        returnValue: Any?,
        returnType: MethodParameter,
        mavContainer: ModelAndViewContainer,
        webRequest: NativeWebRequest
    ) {
        println("Test return handler gets called")
        delegate.handleReturnValue(returnValue, returnType, mavContainer, webRequest)
    }
}

And this is how I try to configure it
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer

@Configuration
class CustomWebMvcConfigurer : WebMvcConfigurer {


    @Autowired
    lateinit var handler: HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerImpl


    override fun addReturnValueHandlers(handlers: MutableList<HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler>) {
        // Get the default handler from the Spring context and wrap it with the custom one
        handlers.add(handler)
    }


}


Currently I am getting

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

Description:
The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:
HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerImpl
How can I ensure that my custom handler is correctly registered and invoked?
